# htaccess mod_rewrite - rewrite parameter without the need of any extension

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got this htaccess inside `example.com/go/`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /go/?there=$1 [L]
```

so `example.com/go/ttt.html` becomes `example.com/go/?there=ttt`

But I don't want any extension, I want to remove `.html` so I tried:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /go/?there=$1 [L]
```

But it's not working, `example.com/go/ttt` gives **Internal Server Error**

How to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
```

So , code will be :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /go/?there=$1 [L]
```

Then test `example.com/go/ttt`

**UPDTAE :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /go/$1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /go/?there=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Not work this way, is it the server fault? Any other suggestions?

Comment: sorry , i was hurry there is an addition code , just wait me a second

Comment: The first code you pasted  RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /go/?there=$1 [L] work fine with example.com/go/ttt.html right?

Comment: Yes the first one works, just want to use rewrite rule without .html